# Dell G3 15 only recognizes external monitor, laptop screen black

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, dell

I have Dell G3 15 and I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and at first my second monitor was not working.

I have installed the nvidia driver as such:
[image]

And after I performed this tutorial: http://ae0bq.org/?p=137

At this point only my second hdmi connected display seems to work. My laptop display remains black.

I aslo tried switching from gdm3 and lightdm with the same output. Under wayland, on gdm3 I was able to work on my laptop display but not on the hdmi connected one.

How can I make both displays work? (there is no hardware failure)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after my Nvidia Driver create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`   file containing only Nvidia monitor (external ones) configurations. Since there was no further configuration of internal monitor (which don't use nvidia drives) the computer was only working with the external ones.

To fix it i only deleted the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I hope it fix your issues

Answer (score -1):

May be a dumb question but are you sure your display is enabled ? Settings -> display (I guess mine in french is "Affichage")

What happens when you unplug your external monitor ?

[image]

Comment: Under wayland: I have another active display there but no image on it. Under xorg: I do not see the latop display after login